# How to account for differences in measured DC resistance of motor winding

Tags: resistance, brushless-dc-motor, inductance-measurement

I have five small brushless DC motors from KDE, model# KDE2315XF-2050.  The specs for this motor state that the winding resistance is 0.034 Ohms,
and having conversed with KDE, they state the winding inductance is ~3.6uH as measured with a scope at 150kHz.

I want to verify these values, and according to KDE they use the method outlined in Tektronix's document "Capacitance and Inductance Measurements Using an
Oscilloscope and a Function Generator", document ID 75W-28152-1.

KDE modified some of the variables in their example video on YouTube such that the voltage amplitude is 2.5V, and the test frequency is 150kHz.

I performed this test myself using a value of R reference being measured at 995.9 Ohms (using a calibrated Fluke 289 multimeter), freq generator set at 2.5V amplitude and 150kHz.  I then measured the
windings of 5 motors.  The following are the average results for all five motors:

```
Average Inductance = 3.46uH

Average Resistance = 0.5972 Ohms
```

When I measure the DC resistance of all five motors using the Lo Ohms setting of the Fluke 289 I get an average resistance reading
of:

```
0.031 Ohms.
```

Using the scope and the I-V method the inductance jives with the specs, but not the resistance.  I trust my multimeter to provide an accurate DC resistance measurement.

If I adjust the voltage amplitude and frequency to 5V and 50kHz I get:

```
R = 0.08584 Ohms
L = 3.814uH
```

So my question is this, why is there such a difference in the winding resistance between the two methods of measurement (scope vs. multimeter)?

As an FYI I do not have a high end scope of function generator, so I do expect a difference but not so much.  Also note it has been 20+ years since I have worked with electronics at
this level.  If I am missing something please forgive me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The motor resistance is specified at DC, not at high frequency. At high frequency, you get a skin effect, eddy currents,... which add looses. For this reason it is normal that you get different results DC vs. HF.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  So what's the point then of having the calculation for resistance in the Tektronix document?

Comment: @mike So you can account for the resistance effects that do not appear at DC.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  You guys have given me a few things to consider and brush up on.